# How to show this expression is always a perfect square?

Tags: combinatorics

The number of tilings of an $m \times n$ board with $2 \times 1$ dominoes (each placed either horizontally or vertically on two squares of the board) has been shown to be

$$\sqrt{\prod_{j=1}^m \prod_{k=1}^n ({2 \cos{\frac{j\pi}{m+1}}} + 2i \cos{\frac{k \pi}{n+1}})}$$

Is there any simple way (besides showing that this counts something) to show that the expression under the square-root is always equal to the square of an integer for any choices of $m,n$ where either $m$ or $n$ (or both) is even?

Comment: Was gonna say, unless $m,n$ both odd, but then I see it returns $0$. Do you have a link for this result? Would love to see a proof...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domino_tiling#Counting_tilings_of_regions

Comment: anyway, the second expression in the wikipedia section has no square or fourth root.

Comment: http://www.math.brown.edu/~rkenyon/papers/dimerlecturenotes.pdf

Comment: Proof of this result in section 4.14 in above link, it uses a result from section 3.12. Summary of proof as the determinant of the Kasteleyn matrix gives the number of domino tilings (proven in 3.12). The expression in question is shown (in 4.14) to be the determinant of the matrix whose determinant is that of the Kasteleyn matrix squared. Still don't know how to show we get an integer without counting something...